# How to add a box with longitude/latitude tick marks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using QGIS version2.18.2 to generate a map. I need a box to embrace the map, and the box needs to show tick marks from the corresponding longitude and latitude of the mapped area. I've searched the way of adding this kind of box, but has no solid solution. Hopefully I can get some guidances here. It shall look like the box below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using Print Composer:

1. `Project | New Print Composer` to start Composer.
2. `Layeout | Add Map` will give you the current view you have on QGIS. Hold C-key and use mouse to move your map to fit your Composer area.
3. Select `Item properties` tab (RHS) and scroll down to **Grids**. Add new Grids by clicking-on green plus button **+**.
4. Check the box on `Draw "Grid " grid` and choose `Grid type` - "Frame and annotation only". The most tricky part of your question is that you need 0.05 degrees interval for Y, while 0.04 degrees interval for X. Modify `Interval` and `Offset` to fit for your aimed coordinate annotations.
5. To annotate coordinates check on the box of `Draw coordinates` and select "Show latitude only" for `Left` and "Show longitude only" for `bottom`.
6. To add a border line, select "Line border" in the `Grid frame | Frame style` option.